# Building a Podcast app with MediaBrowserService

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am following the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview) on how to properly build a media application. So far I built a small demo where I can play and pause a media item streamed over http.

On UI side I am starting the playback like this:

```
mediaController.transportControls.playFromUri("http://someuri.mp3", null);
```

and on the service side I am handling it something like this:

```
callback = MediaSessionCompat.Callback(){

  override fun onPlayFromUri(uri: Uri, extras: Bundle?){
    // do some preparations
    // ...

    myPlayerImpl.playFromUri(uri)
  }

}
```

Till this point everything works fine. But now I would like to go one step further and implement the skip functionality: `skip to next` and `skip to prev`. Obviously in order to do that I need a playlist; the rest of the logic would stay the same.

And this is where I stuck.

I found `onGetRoot()` and `onLoadChildren()`. If I understood it correctly, these two methods should be responsible for building the playlist and then pass it over to the UI for rendering. Now, all the examples that I saw, including the [UAMP sample app](https://github.com/android/uamp), show how to load the playlist using a hard-coded playlist and a hard-coded root it. In my case however, the playlist should be loaded dynamically depending on what Podcast the user is seeing. So I imagine that I should be able to pass the podcast id to be returned by `onGetRoot()`, somehow, and then download the episodes and send the result back to UI.

So I can't figure out how to do this: pass the podcast id to the `MediaBrowserService`. I would realy appreciate any suggestions or ideas on how to properly solve this.

Comment: What makes you think you **need** a playlist? You can do whatever you want in `onSkipToNext` and `onSkipToPrevious`.

Comment: Well, I need to play either the previous or the next episode. But how do I do that without having my list of episodes already preloaded?